# Pass value from pop up to parent window via window.opener

Tags: php, javascript

I know that similar questions have been asked before but I have not been able to find one that uses window.opener in the same way that I have.

I have a page that opens a pop up to display/edit/delete values in a db.  Once it has done it's thing I use this to end the script and go back to the parent.

```
die( "<script>window.opener.location.reload();window.close();</script>");
```

This works well but I would like to pass a value back to the parent that I can use $_GET to retrieve.

This is for a a calendar and I use the above code to refresh the parent page so that the changes made to the diary event displayed in the pop up are automatically displayed (otherwise the user has to refresh themselves).  At the moment when the page refreshes it goes back to the default date which is today rather than the date of the event affected.  I would like to pass the date back to the parent

tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.reload()`, just navigate to the same page with the querystring you want by setting `location.search`:

```
window.opener.location.search = "?value=" + val; window.close();
```

Comment: sorry for the delay in the response, I've only just been able to check for answers.  Will this reload the page?  I need it to reload the page to show the new entry added via the pop up

Comment: Yes, it causes the browser to navigate to the same page with the given querystring arguments (ie, `location.search`).

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it, thought of a much simpler answer, I used sessions instead, kept it simple

Answer (score 1):

you can put a js code into your `popup window`

```
<script>
    window.opener._newVar = "new value for parent window";
    // now you can direct access (_newVar) after popup closed.
</script>
```